# grep the word within word boudary across multiple line using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I do have a file that contains something like:

```
physicalcard = 1
id = 1
status
control
step
...

physicalcard = 0
id = 2
status
control
step
...
```

in notepad++, there is regular expression feature.  How to make use of it so i can grep the words from id til control across multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```
^id\s*=.*?\ncontrol
```

you need check the `. matches newline` checkbox.

Comment: You can also use inline mode modifiers instead of having to check the `. matches newline` checkbox. `(?s)^id\s*=.*?\ncontrol`

Comment: it does help.  But i don't really don't understand how it work.  Could you pls elaborate on it?  Is there any reference (book or website) u can recommend?  So i can learn it.  thanks